# (Rows to columns / Pivot) + SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have some tables in MySQL:

```
+---------+--------------+---------+    +---------+----------+
|             TABLE 1              |    |       TABLE 2      |
+---------+--------------+---------+    +---------+----------+
| id_user |  testnumber1 |   score |    | id_user | username |
+---------+--------------+---------+    +---------+----------+
|    1    |       1      |    90   |    |    1    |   aaa    |
|    1    |       2      |    80   |    |    2    |   bbb    |
|    1    |       3      |    70   |    |    3    |   ccc    |
|    2    |       1      |    60   |    +---------+----------+
|    2    |       2      |    66   |
|    2    |       3      |    77   |
|    3    |       1      |    90   |
|    3    |       2      |    80   |
|    3    |       3      |    70   |
+---------+--------------+---------+
```

Is it possible to get this:

```
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|                      TABLE RESULT                    |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+ 
| id_user |  testnumber1 |  testnumber2 |  testnumber3 |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|    1    |      90      |      80      |      70      |
|    2    |      60      |      66      |      77      |
|    3    |      90      |      80      |      70      |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

?

What statement can I use to get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to `PIVOT` the columns into rows. Unfortunately, MySQL has no `PIVOT` table operator. But you can use the `CASE` expression to do this, like so:

```
SELECT
  id_user,
  MAX(CASE WHEN  testnumber1 = 1 THEN score END) AS testnumber1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN  testnumber1 = 2 THEN score END) AS testnumber2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN  testnumber1 = 3 THEN score END) AS testnumber3
FROM Table
GROUP BY id_user;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5a60/1)

Comment: thanks Mahmoud Gamal, but i have some question again.
how to count testnumber1,testnumber2,testnumber3.
and make new column for sum result.

i'm sorry, i'm a newbie...

Comment: @tombom do you know of a book that discussed the issues in depth? or some ebook?

Comment: @Najiullah.com Seeing that you not even submitted a try on a SELECT statement, any book will do...

Comment: btw, for the last request... `SELECT
  id_user,
  MAX(CASE WHEN  testnumber1 = 1 THEN score END) AS testnumber1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN  testnumber1 = 2 THEN score END) AS testnumber2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN  testnumber1 = 3 THEN score END) AS testnumber3,
  SUM(score) as Total
FROM Table
GROUP BY id_user;`

Comment: @Najiullah.com And next time, please, describe your problem in the question title. You wouldn't ask if you hadn't any problem, right?

Comment: @Najiullah.com - Here is a cool book as a start: [**SQL Queries for Mere Mortals(R): A Hands-On Guide to Data Manipulation in SQL**](http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Queries-Mere-Mortals-Manipulation/dp/0201433362). And read more in the [**MySQL Reference**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/)

Comment: Thanks for your answers @tombom Mahmoud Gamal and NaNNy.